# Storing up to the most recent N elements in a Postgres jsonb field

Tags: arrays, jsonb, postgresql-9.5, fifo

I have a Postgres table with a JSONB column in which I want to store an array. The array starts off having 0 elements but will grow to hold up to N elements.

With every update I need to append one element to this field until the number of elements has grown from 0 to N. After that every time a new element is added the oldest one should be dropped such that the array only holds the most recent N elements.

So if the table is **myTable**, the JSONB array column is **myArray**, the incoming element is **myElement** and N is 10, I would have...

```
UPDATE myTable SET myArray=???
```

Can anyone provide the query that would append elements in this way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. And if you are really embracing a de-normalized data model using JSON, using a current version of Postgres will be a lot easier in the long run anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that implements the check on the array length:

```
create or replace function append_element(p_array jsonb, p_new_element anyelement, p_max_elements int)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
begin
  p_array := p_array || to_jsonb(p_new_element);
  
  while jsonb_array_length(p_array) > p_max_elements loop 
    p_array := p_array - 0;
  end loop;
  return p_array;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
immutable;
```

Which can be used in an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = append_element(the_column, 'a new one', 10)
where ....;
```

This assumes that `the_column` stores the array directly, e.g. `["one", "two"]` - not in some sub-structure like e.g. `{"elements": ["one", "two"]}`

The function could be improved by checking if the passed `jsonb` value is indeed an array and throwing an error otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @a_horse_with_no_name!!! One thing I didn't mention: I am not directly running queries on the Postgres DB: I'm using a console that abstracts the DB and that parses strings and passes them as queries to the DB. The console does fine with most queries, but unfortunately it doesn't understand "plpgsql" and I wasn't able to try this.

I restructured the DB and resolved my problem. Thanks again!!!